# Nsis temp folder

Tags: nsis

```
Function .onInit
DetailPrint "Temp folder - $TEMP"
System::Call 'Kernel32::GetTempFileName(t $TEMP, t "tmp", i 0, t.r0) i.r1 
DetailPrint "Temp folder name - $0" //$0  gives empty string
FunctionEnd
```

When I call `Kernel32::GetTempFileName` in `.onInit` function i retrieves an empty file name. But when i call it from section everything is ok!

Can you explain me why?

Comment: The code you posted does not even compile...

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you just call [`InitPluginsDir`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#initpluginsdir) in `.onInit` and use [`$PLUGINSDIR`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#varconstant) as temp folder. It will be deleted automatically on exit.

> $PLUGINSDIR
>
> The path to a temporary folder created upon the first usage of a
>   plug-in or a call to InitPluginsDir. This folder is automatically
>   deleted when the installer exits.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to quote all string parameters when using `System::Call`:

```
Section
System::Call 'Kernel32::GetTempFileName(t "$TEMP", t "tmp", i 0, t.r0) i.r1'
DetailPrint |$0|
SectionEnd
```

Please consider using `$pluginsdir` like the other answer suggests, it is a much better solution because it will not leave behind junk on the end-users machine...